# PL/SQL developer (allroundautomations.com) hangs while compiling Package Body

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, timeout, plsqldeveloper

i am using PL/SQL developer by allroundautomations. Some days back i was able to create package and package body. i did recompiled several times package body. But since yesterday, i am facing this issue. 
I open package body and click on recompile (without doing any changes) it hangs.

please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Perhaps you could wait for a while until you see `ORA-04021 timeout occurred while waiting to lock object`. Even if you close the `PL/SQL Developer` window or end the process, the previous session might still be `ACTIVE`. You can kill that session and try again.

You can query `v$locked_object` to find out.

2. It is also possible that, the package is in use by some other session when you try to compile it.

You can query `v$sqlarea` and `v$session` to find out.

Comment: i get "timeout occured while waiting to lock objects" this error after long time.

Comment: i tried to query v$locked_object table but it says table of view does not exist

Comment: It means you do not have the privilege to access v$locked_object.

Comment: Thanks Lalit. I need to check with administrator to resolve this issue. Thanks for your quick response.